# When I using chrome.webrequest,I get the requestbody.raw,how can I change it to Json formation?

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension

I need to convert the request.raw data to Json formation.How can I do this?

Comment: the body raw just like this:     {raw: Array(1)}
raw: Array(1)
0:
bytes: ArrayBuffer(439)
[[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(439) [123, 34, 99, 114, 97, 119, 108, 101, 114, 73, 110, 102, 111, 34, 58, 34, 48, 97, 110, 65, 102, 120, 110, 100, 88, 121, 108, 111, 113, 57, 69, 105, 98, 73, 52, 71, 53, 111, 48, 100, 75, 57, 74, 48, 48, 54, 95, 75, 103, 4,85, 90, 48, 79, 50, 114, 84, 45, 117, 68, 65, 75, 81, 105, 70, 107, 70, 9, 106, 45, 70, 72, 117, 78, 51, 68, 54, 54, 67, 57, 101, 88, 99, 105, 106, 102, 102, 70, 50, 111, 52, 109, 54, …]
[[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(439)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]

Comment: [Convert it into a string](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+arraybuffer+to+string+javascript) first then use JSON.parse.